# Unable to connect hive in kerberos mode

Tags: hadoop, hive, kerberos, hortonworks-sandbox

Here is the code to connect to hive in kerberos mode

```
import java.sql.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation;

public class hive2 {
  public static void main (String args[]) {
    try {
      org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration conf = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration();
      conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos");
      UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
      UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("hive/ambari2012.howard2012.local@HOWARD2012.LOCAL", "/etc/security/keytabs/hive.service.keytab");
      Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
      System.out.println("getting connection");
      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://ambari2012:10000/;principal=hive/ambari2012.howard2012.local@HOWARD2012.LOCAL");
      System.out.println("got connection");
      con.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

the issue is doesnt matter what keytab I pass it's always giving the below error -

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
java.io.IOException: Login failure for hive/ambari2012.howard2012.local@HOWARD2012.LOCAL from keytab /etc/security/keytabs/hive.service.keytab
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(UserGroupInformation.java:921)
    at hive.connect.java.hive.connect.java.App.main(App.java:21)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user
```

I don't think it's even trying to check if the right keytab is given to it.
How should I ensure it's reading the correct keytab file and also if the keytab file is not present it should give unable to locate the keytab

Please let me know if I have to copy the keytab ,krb files in my local machine

Comment: did you use `klist -kt /etc/security/keytabs/hive.service.keytab` ? what did you get?

Comment: yep there might be something with your keytab looking at the error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can connect to a kerberized HIVE this way.
Try using a JAAS file https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/LoginConfigFile.html 
and add the 2 following properties to your JVM :

```
-Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=False
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=jaas.conf
```

Sample file jaas.conf :

```
com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.initiate
{ com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useKeyTab      =true
  useTicketCache =false
  doNotPrompt    =true
  principal ="hive/ambari2012.howard2012.local@HOWARD2012.LOCAL"
  keyTab    ="/etc/security/keytabs/hive.service.keytab"
  debug     =false;
};

Client
{ com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useKeyTab      =true
  useTicketCache =false
  doNotPrompt    =true
  principal ="hive/ambari2012.howard2012.local@HOWARD2012.LOCAL"
  keyTab    ="/etc/security/keytabs/hive.service.keytab"
  debug     =false;
};
```

Comment: Thanks Harold , after doing some tweeks the error is now showing   "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil.hasKerberosKeyTab(Ljavax/security/auth/Subject;)Z"   ......will that resolved with Jaas ? thanks for you help

Comment: I don't think so. It looks like something is wrong with your environment.
Actually it is possible to connect with UGI; An example here:
https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/1807/connecting-to-kerberos-enabled-hive-via-jdbc-direc.html
This is how beeline works

Answer (score 0):

I was missing jar files so if you add all jar files it's fine, here is the complete code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation;

public class App {
private static Connection hiveConnection;
// get Hive Connection
public static void  main(String [] args) throws IOException, SQLException {


    String principal="principal";
    String keytab="keytab";
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try{ Process p = rt.exec("kinit -k -t " + keytab + " " + principal);
    p.waitFor(); } 
    catch(InterruptedException exception)
    {
    System.out.println("wait for threw an exception - it was interrupted"); 
    exception.printStackTrace(); 
    }
    catch (IOException exception){
           System.out.println("Exception in running kinit process") ;
            exception.printStackTrace();  
   }
            System.out.println("Preparing Hive connection1");
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly","false");
            conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos");
            UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
            UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(principal, keytab);


    // Hive Connection
    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
        if(hiveConnection == null) {
            hiveConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://host:10000/;principal=principal;auth=kerberos;kerberosAuthType=fromSubject");
           // return hiveConnection;
            System.out.println("Got Connection");
        } else {
        //return hiveConnection;
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       // return null;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // return null;
    }
}
}
```